# object detection and classification of images based on temperature numbers ranges

Tags: object-detection

Can I make object detection with ranges as classes and not names?
I mean suppose I have the following classes:

```
class_1: "18-20"
class_2: "21-23"
class_3: "24-26"
class_4: "27-29"
```

Suppose the previous describe temperatures from images. The testing images in order to get matched should be of the same classes right? For instance can I have test images such as one number: "19", "23" and not ranges? But each test image to belong to a class when object detection is made in the inference part? Is there any way to make that scheme work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a neural network backpropagates based on a single error value.